# Осуществление ajax-технологии

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Доброго времени суток!
Есть форма регистрации. Есть такой вот скрипт:

```
 $(function() {
    $("#form-regis").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
      var formmethod = $(this).attr("method");
      var postData = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: formmethod,
        url: formURL,
        data:postData,
        cache: false,

        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }

    });

    return false;
  });
});
```

Мои мизерные знания `JavaScript` и `jQuery` не оставляют мне возможности вывести всё это на страницу. Форма регистрации в модальном окне, поэтому без `Ajax` мне тут не обойтись. В консоли я принимаю массив ошибок, именно те, которые допускаю при заполнении формы. Помогите вывести их списком на страницу. Сначала с этим бы разобраться, а там дальше надо будет при отсутствии ошибок скрыть форму и вывести, что регистрация успешна и на почту письмо с подтверждением отправлено.

Извиняюсь, за неполную инфу. Данные приходят в формате JSON, в такой структуре "поле: массив/объект ошибок"

Сейчас сделал так:

```
success: function (errors) {
    console.log(errors);
    var out = '';
    if (errors[0].name) out += "<p>"+errors[0].name+"</p>";
    if (errors[0].email) out += "<p>"+errors[0].email+"</p>";
    if (errors[0].password) out += "<p>"+errors[0].password+"</p>";

    $('#errors-block').html(out).fadeIn();
 }
```

Но если заполнять без ошибок ругается такой строчкой:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

*Laravel 5*

Comment: Если не обладаете хорошими навыками в `JS`, то не беритесь верстать сами - только нервы потратите.
А по вопросу - мало данных. В каком формате принимаются данные? Как нужно их выводить и куда (обычно это диктует тема сайта)?

Comment: @Other 
В формате json. Вывести просто в ту же модалку, добавлю там див с айди "errors", и как можно перебрать в цикле все ошибки в сакссэссе вместо консоль.лога? Чтобы они появились чуть выше самой формы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот код который я использую в ларавел приложении. Все работает отлично

```
$.ajax({
        url     : form.attr("action"),
        type    : form.attr("method"),
        data    : formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        },
        error :function( errors ) {
            output = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><h4><i class='icon fa fa-ban'></i> Возникла ошибка!</h4><ul>";
            $.each(errors.responseJSON, function(index, error){
                output += "<li>" + error + "</li>";
            });
            output += "</ul></div>";
            $('#append').html(output);
        },
        success: function(data){
            output = "<div class='alert alert-success'><h4><i class='icon fa fa-check'></i> Готово!</h4><ul>";
            output +=  data.success;
            output += "</ul></div>";
            $('#append').html(output);
            setTimeout(function(){
                window.location.replace('{{ url('panel/catalog') }}')}, 3500
            );
        }
    })
```

Comment: Здравствуйте! Я в принципе уже разобрался, только у меня скудно в плане параметров Ajax. Я не указывал dataType, и заголовок с токеном тоже отсутствует.

Answer (score 2):

```
success: function (errors) {
    console.log(errors);
    var out = '';
    for(err in errors) {
       out += "<p>"+errors[0][err]+"</p>"
    }
    if(out != '') {
       $('#errors-block').html(out).fadeIn();
    }
 }
```

if (errors[0].name) - вернет ошибку если такого свойства нет, здесь нужна проверка
 `if(typeof errors[0].name !== 'undefined')`

Comment: Спасибо! С божьей и вашей, общей помощью, скрипя, но разобрался.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(function() {
   var form = $("#form-regis");
        form.submit(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
          var formmethod = $(this).attr("method");
          var postData = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: formmethod,
            url: formURL,
            data:postData,
            cache: false,

            success: function (data) {
                var res = JSON.parce(data);
              for(err in res) {
                $('[name=' + err + ']', form).after('<span class="error">' + res[err] + '</span>');
              }
            }

        });

        return false;
      });
    });
```

Это в случае если в ответ приходит {"fieldName":"errorText", ....}

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Спасибо за отклик.